# Backjumping, CSP, AIMA book

Tags: artificial-intelligence, backtracking, constraint-programming

Context: backjumping is an optimization to vanilla backtracking. It reduces the search tree's branching factor by intelligently jumping back to a node which is the cause of the failure (instead of backtracking to the chronological parent).

Chapter 5 of Artificial Intelligence, a Modern Approach, 3rd ed, [p149-150](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/2nd-ed/newchap05.pdf) gives a brief example of how to create the conflict set during backjumping.

The example is about coloring [Australia's map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkEPo.png).

Quote from the problematic part:

> The “terminal” failure of a branch of the search always occurs because
>   a variable’s domain becomes empty; that variable has a standard
>   conflict set. In our example, SA fails, and its conflict set is (say)
>   {WA,NT,Q}. We backjump to Q, and Q absorbs the conflict set from SA
>   (minus Q itself, of course) into its own direct conflict set, which is
>   {NT,NSW}; the new conflict set is {WA,NT,NSW}. That is, there
>   is no solution from Q onward, given the preceding assignment to {WA,NT,NSW}. Therefore, we **backtrack to NT**, the most recent of these.
>   NT absorbs {WA,NT,NSW} − {NT} into its own direct conflict set {WA},
>   giving {WA,NSW} (as stated in the previous paragraph). Now the
>   algorithm **backjumps to NSW**, as we would hope.

I'm struggling to understand the emphasized bits:

1. Backtracking to NT. In what way / why is NT the most recent?
2. Backjumping to NSW. Why?

Comment: Oh, the first answer in minutes! I knew that the SO community would be helpful. Would the person who answered with -1 be so kind and elaborate his/her answer? 
How does this numerical value answer any of my open-ended questions?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but this question does not have sufficient context to be answerable. I am guessing the example is of colouring a map of Australian states, but you need at least the graph and the attempted decision order to be able to answer this.

Comment: @xulavokes Could you provide the pseudocode of Backjumping?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to Q1 is in the previous paragraph, the key is the decision order:

> Consider again the partial assignment {WA = red, NSW = red} (which, from our earlier discussion, is inconsistent).
>   Suppose we try T = red next and then assign NT, Q, V , SA.
>   We know that no assignment can work for these last four variables, so eventually we run out of values to try at NT.

NT is the most recent in the sense that it is the top of the stack at the point where this example is being discussed.

We backjump to NSW as this is the last decision which intersects with the conflict set.

Comment: Is it possible to do backjumping with assignement? I think conflict set can confuse the assignment set.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking: If you use the full assignment as the conflct you are just backtracking not backjumping as whatever the last two decisions will always be in the "conflict".